# grep + grep + sed = sed: no input files

Tags: sed, grep

Can anybody help me please?

```
grep " 287 " file.txt | grep "HI" | sed -i 's/HIS/HID/g' 

sed: no input files
```

Tried also xargs

```
grep " 287 " file.txt | grep HI | xargs sed -i 's/HIS/HID/g'
sed: invalid option -- '6'
```

This works fine

```
grep " 287 " file.txt | grep HI
```

Comment: `-i` is for "in-place editing" you can't "in-place edit" a stream so `sed` is expecting a file but you haven't given it any.

Comment: yep, but if I remove -i it wont write it to the file...

Comment: Neither of those commands is writing to a file. If you want the output from `sed` there to go to a file you need to redirect it to a file. `-i` there can't help you. And you can't just stick `> file.txt` on the end either as that will truncate first. That being said `sed` can do all the filtering for you so you don't need `grep` at all.

Comment: grep " 287 " file.txt | grep "HI" | sed 's/HIS/HID/g'

This only prints the output but cant save it

Comment: Like I just said you need to redirect the output to a file (e.g. put `> newfile.txt` at the end of that). Alternatively, just let `sed` find the lines that match those patterns and then you can use `-i`.

Comment: > newfile.txt This only output the grep lines, not the entire file...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to keep your pipeline:

```
f=file.txt
tmp=$(mktemp)
grep " 287 " "$f" | grep "HI" | sed 's/HIS/HID/g' > "$tmp" && mv "$tmp" "$f"
```

Or, simplify:

```
sed -i -n '/ 287 / {/HI/ s/HIS/HID/p}' file.txt
```

That will filter out any line that does not contain " 287 " and "HI" -- is that what you want? I suspect you really want this:

```
sed -i '/ 287 / {/HI/ s/HIS/HID/}' file.txt
```

For lines that match `/ 287 /`, execute the commands in braces. In there, for lines that match `/HI/`, search for the first "HIS" and replace with "HID". sed implicitly prints all lines if `-n` is not specified.

Other commands that do the same thing:

```
awk '/ 287 / && /HI/ {sub(/HIS/, "HID")} {print}' file.txt > new.txt
perl -i -pe '/ 287 / and /HI/ and s/HIS/HID/' file.txt
```

awk does not have an "in-place" option (except `gawk -i inplace` for recent gawk versions)

Comment: Yes, last one works perfectly, can you explain it a bit please?

Comment: how can I change file.txt for $1.

$1 is user input when running sh.

Comment: how do you think you would do that?

Comment: Recommend you ask a new question