# How to use sed with hdfs?

Tags: sed, hdfs

Im trying change a special character (Þ) for ; but from hdfs not found. The command that i used is this:

`hdfs dfs -cat path/file.txt | sed -i 's/Þ/;/g' | hadoop fs -put -f - path/file.txt`

where:

1. `hdfs dfs -cat` is for getting the HDFS file content
2. `sed -i 's/Þ/;/g'`  for replace Þ for ;
3. `hadoop fs -put -f - path/file.txt` is for overwriting the original file in HDFS

When i run this command i have this error:

```
sed: no input files
cat: Unable to write to output stream.
```

If i ejecute hdfs dfs -cat path/file.txt i can see the content ¿What is going on?

Edit 1:

I deleted the -i for the sed and i dont have the error in sed, but the console show this:

```
put:`path/file.txt': No such file or directory
cat: cat: Unable to write to output stream.
```

Thanks!!

Comment: `sed -i 's/Þ/;/g'` =>  `sed 's/Þ/;/g'`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [grep + grep + sed = sed: no input files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29284031/grep-grep-sed-sed-no-input-files)

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew i deleted the -i and i havent a sed error but now have this


put: path/file.txt No such file or directory
cat: Unable to write to output stream.

Comment: Uh, try `ls -l path/file.txt` ?  `path` isn't supposed to be `$path` or something?

Answer (score 1):

```
hdfs dfs -cat path/file.txt | sed 's/Þ/;/g' | hadoop fs -put -f - path/file.txt
```

It works for me in this way.